# How do I turn off speech-to-text censorship in Android 7?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, voice-recognition

This was the most recent article I found on it:

https://www.howtogeek.com/303489/how-to-disable-the-profanity-filter-in-google-assistant/

Problem is that the triple dot dropdown menu isn't there. I have an icon that looks like a new email message and one that looks like a compass needle. I've searched the settings for "censor" and "block" and there are no results.

How do I stop it from turning "fuck" into "f***" in Android 7? LG G5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LG rebel 3 running Android nougat 7.0 there are a couple of paths to the Block offensive words toggle.

First it spelled f*** missing the k but then I manually typed in the word. When I tried by voice after that it was spelled properly and fully.
The path's to the Block offensive words toggle are:

1. /Language & Keyboard --> Google voice typing --> Block Offensive words toggle.
2. /Google services --> Search, Assistant, Voice --> Voice --> Block offensive words toggle.

Comment: In Android 8 this is in `General -> Apps & Notifications -> Default apps -> Assist & voice input -> Assist app (gear) -> Block Offensive words (toggle)` 

(updated my phone since posting this)

Answer (score 0):

On Android 7.1.2, I go to:

- Settings
- Language and Keyboard
- Keyboard and Input Methods / Google Voice Typing

"Block offensive words" is 2nd from the bottom. I've tried toggling it successfully. This works for me when I use Google Keep.